# CodeMirror error with MeteorJs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, codemirror

I'm using meteorJs 1.4 and trying to use the `mizzao:sharejs-codemirror` package but I keep getting this error when I try to use it

> failed to get ops for tNvo2iHyPAamPeHAd: MongoError: Failed to parse:
>   sort: "_id.v". 'sort' field must be of BSON type Object.

here is some code: server side

```
this.Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");

Meteor.startup(() => {
  if(!Documents.findOne()){
    Documents.insert({title:"new Document"});
  }
});
```

client side:

```
this.Documents = new Mongo.Collection("documents");

Template.editor.helpers({
  docid:function(){
    myDocument = Documents.findOne();
    if(myDocument){
      return myDocument._id;
    }
    else{
      return undefined;
    }
  }
});
```

markup:

```
<head>
  <title>textcircle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>welcome to textcircle</h1>

  {{> editor}}
</body>

<template name="editor">
  {{> sharejsCM docid=docid id="editor"}}
</template>
```

Can someone please explain to me what this means. Thanks.

Comment: could you add some code snippets?

Comment: I got the same error if I am updating my documents. I tried to solve the problem using the following command

    meteor reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will completely help in your case but apparently there are some issues with Meteor 1.4 and shareJS / CodeMirror (check the repo for more info), so this is a workaround. I was running Meteor 1.4 and also building an app using shareJS / CodeMirror but mine would get stuck on "loading..." in the code mirror pane / div and not get any further (using Firefox on Ubuntu). First, I tried "meteor reset" but that didn't fix it. I tried just running Meteor as a previous version with a command switch but the MongoDB would fail to start. I tried creating a project instead with 1.3.x and was still having the same issue, but when I created a new Meteor app with version 1.2.1 it worked and the CodeMirror pane was functional.

To create a new Meteor 1.2.1 app, run:

meteor create [appName] --release 1.2.1

To get it up and going, I copied my client and server files over from my 1.4 app, and deleted the auto-generated files. I commented out the import statements, but other than that it was pretty smooth. Just add the packages you're using and you'll have to add session too most likely, but that should get you up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue as yours and I'm using Metero 1.4.2.3.
I reset my project using **meteor reset** and it worked for me! 
As soon as you stop your server you will need to reset it again before running otherwise you will get that MongoError. Annoying but it's kind of a fix ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and sharejs-cm didn't give me any troubles, I do think that on your client code you should define 'myDocument' as a variable before you use it in the condition, even though meteor doesn't complain... javascript will take anything that you give to it and won't always tell you why it fails when it does.

```
var myDocument = Documents.findOne();
```

If you are still having issues, be a little more specific with the errors that are being displayed.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This error has something to do with the version of meteor you are using in your application. Basically its a version mismatch. Try running this code in your command prompt.

meteor update --all-packages

This worked for me.

Comment: You should edit your answer, so that the command is in a code block, e.g. inside back ticks: `